# Changing multiple button color separately when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having troubles with my javascript code, I have a snippet that creates a number of button depending on the loop range, the buttons share the same class but the ids are different

```
<div class="panel-footer" id="loop">
    <ul class="post-action">
         {% for i in range %}
                <button class="btn btn-success guess" id="{{ i }}" value="{{ i }}" onclick="transferField(this.value)">{{ i }} </button>
         {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to change the color of each button when it is clicked and when clicked again changes back to default color but its not working fine, when i click on button 5 it changes color but once i click on button 6, it wont change color until i click button 6 or click another button again. Here is the js code:

```
<script>

        clicked = true;

        $(".guess").click(function(){
            xyz = this.id
            console.log(xyz)
            if(clicked){
                $('#' + this.id).css('background-color', '#FF8E2B');
                clicked  = false;
            } else {
                $('#' + this.id).css('background-color', '#27AE60');
                clicked  = true;
            }
        });


</script>
```

What have i done wrong?

Comment: fyi, `$('#' + this.id)` is simply `$(this)` ... and secondly, you have a single boolean `clicked` which you are trying to use to "store" the state of multiple buttons - one boolean for one button :p

Comment: instead of getting id and using it use this context like  `$(this)`

Comment: @guradio  don't you think on click of button `transferField()` will called not the click code he written?

Comment: @guradio do you mean this 

clicked = true;

   $(".guess").click(function(){
    console.log(this)
    if(clicked){
     $(this).css('background-color', '#FF8E2B');
     clicked  = false;
    } else {
     $(this).css('background-color', '#27AE60');
     clicked  = true;
    }
            });

even this is still not changing the button background seperately

Comment: @AlivetoDie transferField() does something else, not related to the question

Comment: @JaromandaX what do you think i might be the best, because i can have many buttons, no specific number of button

Comment: @molecules  but it will call rather than the code you written.

Comment: I've added an answer @molecules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to "track" the state of multiple buttons using a single var, of course this wont work

try the following instead

```
$(".guess").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var clicked = $this.data('clicked');
    if(clicked) {
        $this.css('background-color', '#FF8E2B');
    } else {
        $this.css('background-color', '#27AE60');
    }
    $this.data('clicked', !clicked);
});
```

Comment: never mind, I missed removing a line - if the logic is still wrong, try `if (!clicked) {` instead of `if (clicked) {`

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is you are using `clicked` as a global variable.

Just store `clicked` in `this`.

```js
   

        $(".guess").click(function(){
            xyz = this.id
            console.log(xyz)
            if(this.clicked){
                $(this).css('background-color', '#FF8E2B');
                this.clicked  = false;
            } else {
                $(this).css('background-color', '#27AE60');
                this.clicked  = true;
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-footer" id="loop">
    <ul class="post-action">
         
                <button class="btn btn-success guess" id="one" value="one" > one</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success guess" id="two" value="two" > two</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success guess" id="three" value="three" > three</button>
         
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. I will try it out

Answer (score 0):

You can store an array of color for each element at `data-*` of element, use `.data()`, `Array.prototype.reverse()` to toggle to array, set `background` to element at index `0` of array

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $(this).css("background", $(this).data().colors.reverse()[0])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-colors='["#FF8E2B", "#27AE60"]' style="background:#FF8E2B">click</button>
```

Comment: The `background` is set here. Did you place `$("button").on("click", function(){})` within `.ready()` handler?

Answer (score 0):

> What have i done wrong?

The main issue you have with your code is that you have *one* variable keeping track of the clicked state of *multiple* button elements.

The way to fix this is to *add state to the element itself* essentially giving *multiple* variables for *multiple* elements.

I'm doing this by adding an `event` object to the callback of the `click` handler and getting `event.currentTarget`. The value of `event.currentTarget` is the element object being clicked. You can add state to this object just like you'd add state to another other javascript object

```
event.currentTarget.clicked = true;
```

Now you can keep track of the state for each element!

```js
// just some simple code to get your template in pure JS, don't worry about the code here
const range = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

const template = `<div class="panel-footer" id="loop">
  <ul class="post-action">
    ${range.map(i => `
      <button class="btn btn-success guess" id="${i}" value="${i}">${i}</button>
    `)}
  </ul>
</div>`;

const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = template;
document.body.appendChild(div);

// here are where the changes start

// var clicked = true; instead of having a global variable to keep track of the state of all your buttons

$(".guess").click(function(event) {
  // you need local state attached to the button
  
  // here we're getting the button element being clicked
  const currentTarget = event.currentTarget;
  xyz = this.id
  console.log(xyz);
  
  // if clicked is truthy
  if (currentTarget.clicked) {
    $('#' + this.id).css('background-color', '#FF8E2B');
    currentTarget.clicked = false;
  } else {
    $('#' + this.id).css('background-color', '#27AE60');
    // set on the element some state
    currentTarget.clicked = true;
  }
});
```

```css
.guess {
  /* start out in the orange state */
  background-color: #FF8E2B;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```